# How to check public IP address range of Google Cloud Storage

Tags: range, google-cloud-storage, ip

Expert

I want to know the public IP address range for Google Cloud Storage in a specific region.
I am planning to upload a file using software from a Windows server, and so I need to set the outbound firewall rules.
It seems that the range for Compute Engine is provided by GCP, but I could not find any for Google Cloud Storage.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#find_ip_range

### The image in AWS S3 is like;
Get-AWSPublicIpAddressRange -Region ap-northeast-1 -ServiceKey S3 | select IpPrefix
IpPrefix

52.92.60.0/22
52.219.68.0/22
52.219.16.0/22
...

Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

What about reversing the concept?
Setup [VPC service control](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/overview) in your GCP resources and configure the [inbound firewall there](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) instead of the outbound firewall on your server.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It is definitely a great idea and I also want to do so but our project is not allowed to use VPC service control function for authentication reasons. That is why I need to set the outbound firewall rules for the server.